# Ansible persistant connection

Tags: networking, ansible

I am getting this warning when I ssh into some cisco equipment.

I am unsure what it means, or how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

> [WARNING]: Persistent connection logging is enabled for all. This will
> log ALL interactions and WILL NOT redact sensitive configuration like
> passwords. USE WITH CAUTION!

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that anything you type will be logged and stored.

Therefore take care when you type things in plaintext, eg passwords.

Obviously, this means a record of your actions/commands (malicious or not) are also tracked.

Providing you know what you're doing and are acting in good faith, there is no reason to worry.